# Django: include other urlpatterns in a single urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I am doing something like this in `myproject.myapp.urls`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',
    (ur'^$', 'index'),
    (ur'^browse/$', 'browse'),
    (ur'^request/new/$', 'new_request'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', 'view1'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/asdf$', 'view2'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/qwer$', 'view3'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/zxcv$', 'view4'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/tyui$', 'view5'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ghjk$', 'view6'),
    (ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/bnm/more-looong-url/$', 'view7'),
    ...
)
```

I've tried to refactor above rules and define them in another file `urls2.py` like this:

```
(ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', include('myproject.myapp.urls2')),
```

but it seems to cause problems with unit tests including urlresolvers.

Is there better way to "refactor" the common part of regular expression (`<url_key>`) here?

Comment: What problems did it cause? Using include('') is usually pretty straightforward. Could you describe the errors it gave, or how the output differed from what you were expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do with this line:

```
(ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', include('myproject.myapp.urls2'))
```

What view is the `url_key` parameter going to be passed to?

I'm not sure why you want to refactor the urlpatterns to begin with, but maybe this would be better?:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

URL_KEY = ur'^(?P<url_key>[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)'

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',
    (ur'^$', 'index'),
    (ur'^browse/$', 'browse'),
    (ur'^request/new/$', 'new_request'),
    (URL_KEY+ur'/$', 'view1'),
    (URL_KEY+ur'/asdf$', 'view2'),
    (URL_KEY+ur'/qwer$', 'view3'),
    ...etc
)
```

Comment: Well, I've fixed my test problems and adopted my original solution still, but this is a good suggestion. So I choose this as answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no django expert, but wouldn't the 'view1' item match all of the other entries below it since it doesn't have a '$' at the end? So the other views wouldn't have a chance to get matched.

Comment: +1 put the catch-all at the end or just include $ for every url.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could simplify the expressions in `myproject.myapp.urls`, and instead pass the information along as a parameter to a function in `myproject.myapp.views`?

I'm not sure what was going wrong in your tests, but generally speaking you'll be able to do more in `myproject.myapp.views` since you don't have to base it all on regex logic.

That function in `myproject.myapp.views` would be a switchboard that calls view1, view2, etc